# Valums File Uploader - Allow single file upload only

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, valums-file-uploader

Is there any way to make [Valums File Uploader](https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload) to accept only a single file?

Right now, with `multiple: false` you cannot limit the number of files to upload but instead you can get the user to upload files one-by-one rather than allowing multiple selection.

I need the user to upload a single file only. If another file is being selected after uploading a file, the uploaded file should be replaced by the current one.

Can anyone help me in how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

To limit uploading to only a single file, I simply used `onComplete` callback and I removed the upload button, hope this helps:

```
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
                $('.qq-upload-button').remove();
            }
```

Comment: That is the solution I finally came up with. But I guess this is not a good solution. What about if user wants to re-upload another file instead of the one that is just uploaded? (change the uploaded picture, say because he/she didn't like it and/or uploaded the wrong picture?)

Comment: I would probably add delete button by the uploaded files' filename. The button would delete that file from server(ajax) and reload file uploader. But thats all external code, separated from uploader.

Answer (score 1):

I think hiding the button is not a very good option, here's what i have done.

I basically overwrote the _storeFileForLater method

```
 qq.FileUploaderBasic.prototype._storeFileForLater = function(id){
                  if(!this._options.multiple){ 

                       this._storedFileIds = [];
                       this._storedFileIds.push(id);
                  }
                  else{
                        this._storedFileIds.push(id);
                      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I force to select one file at time commenting this line

if (this._options.multiple){input.setAttribute("multiple", "multiple");}
and
multiple: qq.UploadHandlerXhr.isSupported(),

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since you posted this, but I just learned that the **multiple: false** parameter is supported in version 2.0 beta of Valums File Uploader.

You can download it [here](http://valums-file-uploader.github.io/file-uploader/).